Singleton member list not propagating values as expected
I have the following functions:
    public static void Handle(RequestModel request)
    {
        var room = GameManager.Instance.Rooms.Find(r => r.RoomId == request.RoomId);
        var player = room.TryGetPlayer(request.ClientId);
        if (player == null) return;

        if (room.isOwner(request.ClientId))
        {
            var kickPlayerRequest = (KickPlayerRequest)request.Data;
            var kickedClient = GameManager.Instance.ClientsInRoom[room.RoomId]
                .Find(p => p.ConnectionInfo.Id == kickPlayerRequest.playerId);
            if (kickedClient == null || kickedClient.ConnectionInfo.Id == request.ClientId) return;

            room.RemovePlayer(kickPlayerRequest.playerId);
            
            GameManager.Instance.ClientsInRoom[room.RoomId].Remove(kickedClient);
            GameManager.Instance.ClientsAwaitingRoom.Add(kickedClient);
            ResponseHandler.HandleKickedUpdate(kickedClient);
            ResponseHandler.HandleRoomUpdate(request.RoomId);
        }
    }

    public void RemovePlayer(Guid playerId)
    {
        var team = GetPlayerTeam(playerId);
        var player = Teams[team].Players.Find(p => p.id == playerId);
        if (player != null)
        {
            Teams[team].Players.Remove(player);
        }
    }

    public static void HandleRoomUpdate(string RoomId)
    {
        var room = GameManager.Instance.Rooms.Find(r => r.RoomId == RoomId);
        JObject response = new JObject();
        response["responseType"] = "update_room";
        response["room"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(room,
            new JsonSerializerSettings 
            { 
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
            });
        
        var clients = GameManager.Instance.ClientsInRoom[RoomId];
        
        foreach (var c in clients)
        {
            response["playerId"] = c.ConnectionInfo.Id;
            c.Send(response.ToString());
        }
    }

I am using a singleton called GameManager as a datasource for now (will move to a database at some point).
The first function, Handle is getting the room correctly from GameManager and the room has a player count of 2.
when the function room.RemovePlayer() runs the player count goes down to 1. However when the function HandleRoomUpdate gets called and it gets the Room from GameManager the room returned has a player count of 2 again. I am not sure why this is happening. Probably something getting copied instead of having a reference update.
Here are some pictures in debug:
Handle getting the room correctly:

Player count updating in room:

as well as GameManagers instance:

But its wrong in HandleRoomUpdate:

If there is anything else i can do to help please feel free to ask, i will clarify. I know this is probably a heap/stack issue, just not sure how to fix it.
EDIT: I just realized that its worth noting that Handle is getting called like so:
    public static void HandleMessage(RequestModel request)
    {
        Type requestType = request.Data.GetType();
        requestType.GetMethod("Handle").Invoke(null, new object?[]{request});
    }

Some further notes, modifying the room variable directly in Handle propagates the changes, implying that the issue is in the RemovePlayer function, following the stack ind debug shows that its the same one, but for some reason the changes made by RemovePlayer dont propagate.
Here is code that I thought would reproduce it but actually gives the results i was expecting...
Room room = new Room();
room.teams[0].players.Add(new Player(0));
room.teams[0].players.Add(new Player(1));
GameManager.Instance.Rooms.Add(room);

// I am running the method this way for consistency
new RequestHandler().GetType().GetMethod("Handle").Invoke(null, new object?[]{room.id});

public class GameManager
{
    public List<Room> Rooms;

    private GameManager()
    {
        Rooms = new List<Room>();
    }
    
    private static GameManager m_instance;

    public static GameManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_instance == null)
            {
                m_instance = new GameManager();
            }

            return m_instance;
        }
    }
}

public class RequestHandler
{
    public RequestHandler()
    {}
    
    public static void Handle(int id)
    {
        Room room = GameManager.Instance.Rooms.Find(r => r.id == id);
        
        // This prints 2
        Console.WriteLine(room.teams[0].players.Count);
        
        room.RemovePlayer(0);
        
        // This prints 1
        Console.WriteLine(room.teams[0].players.Count);
        ResponseHandler.HandleResponse(id);
    }
}

public class ResponseHandler
{
    public static void HandleResponse(int id)
    {
        Room room = GameManager.Instance.Rooms.Find(r => r.id == id);
        // This prints 1 in this example, but in my stack overflow question it prints 2.
        Console.WriteLine(room.teams[0].players.Count);
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public int id;

    public Player(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Team
{
    public List<Player> players;
    
    public Team()
    {
        players = new List<Player>();
    }
}

public class Room
{
    public int id;
    public List<Team> teams;

    public Room()
    {
        id = 0;
        teams = new List<Team>();
        teams.Add(new Team());
    }

    public void RemovePlayer(int player)
    {
        var team = GetPlayersList();
        var playa = teams[team].players.Find(p => p.id == player);
        teams[team].players.Remove(playa);
    }

    public int GetPlayersList()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

I can confirm that inside the handle function:
// the changes from RemovePlayer dont propagate
room.RemovePlayer(kickPlayerRequest.playerId);
// This change does!
room.Status = ROOM_STATUS.GAME_OVER;

So the issue is most likely somewhere in the RemovePlayer function


Is there any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] we could debug?  I'm having trouble understanding what your images are supposed to convey, for some of the reasons mentioned in Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  2) is GameManager.Instance being accessed from multiple threads?  If so, is it thread-safe?


@dbc, i will take a look and give it a shot, GameManager.Instance is being accessed on the same thread, no multithreading. Basically if i edit the room object in the Handle method the changes propagate fine to the HandleRoomUpdate method, but if i alter the room object through room.RemovePlayer() the changes dont get propagated.

@dbc I added code that i thought would reproduce it but it actually gives me exactly what i was expecting my code to give me...

That's actually good news.  Try refactoring your existing code to resemble the working example in some step-by-step manner, there's a good chance that, at one of the steps, you will resolve your bug.

I hope so, ill give it a shot

Are all of your types classes, or are some of them structs?

@dbc everything is a class, it seems that when i update the GameRooms teams array the changes dont propagate ti the other function, but they do propagate to GameManager.Instance.Rooms in the handle function…

You've made it clear that the RemovePlayer call is where the problem is, but you haven't shared the relevant code for the Room type.

I was sleeping, ill share the code

@PeterT.LaCombJr.i also no longer think thats the case, i noticed other values in GameManager.Instance resetting

@dbc I just did some more debugging. There is some form of multithreading happening under the hood on the websocket plugin im using (Fleck for C#). I put breakpoints on two functions and going through them jumps between both of them...
